# Why aren't my Bootstrap columns next to each other?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I used a "bootstrap builder" web app to generate this code to make sure I got it right. But it doesn't appear correctly on my site. Why?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-flex border rounded">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <img src="images/solobee-card.png" </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        s
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        s
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I created a snippet of your markup - although it is missing a closing `</div>` - fixing that is part of the challenge so I left what you have posted in place.

Comment: I would refrain from use of whatever "bootstrap builder" you reference as it seems to get it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `container-flex` utility class, instead use `container` (for fixed width) or `container-fluid` (for full window width)

You can check the overview of containers [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/overview/#containers)

**Note:** Also you have not closed tag `img`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container border rounded">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <img src="images/solobee-card.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      s
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      s
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="container-fluid border rounded">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <img src="images/solobee-card.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      s
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      s
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The closing of the image tag did it, this is what happens when you stare at lines of code for hours on end. True solution: look out the window every half hour to refresh your brain. :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Fix missing `</div>` at the end
2. Fix missing `<img` closing tag, (part of first issue listed)
3. Change class to `container-fluid`

Be sure to view this is "full page" as the default window will wrap it if you run the snippet.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-LtrjvnR4Twt/qOuYxE721u19sVFLVSA4hf/rRt6PrZTmiPltdZcI7q7PXQBYTKyf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid border rounded">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <img src="images/solobee-card.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      s
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      s
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Issue #1 is caused by issue #2, so its only one issue per say

Comment: @dippas  yes, but just pointing out the obvious for clarity as the OP is new to all this